# Jquery filter() Vs Jquery each

Tags: javascript, jquery

What is difference between jQuery `filter()` and `each()` method.

Because both are used to apply looping on a collection.

I heard  about `filter()` method that can filter by collection type.

Comment: filter returns collection items that fullfill a given condition, while foreach is used to apply a function to each element of the collection

Comment: So, did you not find any documentation.

Answer (score 2):

`.each()` => It will simply loop through all the records

ex.

```
 <ul>
     <li>list item 1</li>
     <li>list item 2</li>
     <li>list item 3</li>
     <li>list item 4</li>
     <li>list item 5</li>
     <li>list item 6</li>
  </ul>

  $(li).each(function() { // it will return all li and set its css
      $(this).css( "background-color", "red" );
  });
```

`filter()` => it will only return records which satisfy some condition

ex.

```
<ul>
  <li>list item 1</li>
  <li>list item 2</li>
  <li>list item 3</li>
  <li>list item 4</li>
  <li>list item 5</li>
  <li>list item 6</li>
</ul>

$( "li" ).filter( ":even" ).css( "background-color", "red" ); // it will only set css to even li
```

Answer (score 2):

`$.filter` returns a collection of items that meet a given condition, whilst `$.each` iterates over a collection of items.

Answer (score 2):

I tend to think of `.each()` as a shorthand jQuery way of delaring a `for` loop.

For example:

```js
var i = 0;
$("#list1 li").each(function() {
  console.log("Looped through list item number: " + i++);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="list1">
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
  <li>Item 3</li>
  <li>Item 4</li>
</ul>
```

Could also be written as this in Vanilla JS:

```js
var list = document.getElementById("list2");
var items = list.getElementsByTagName("li");
for(var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
  console.log("Looped through item number: " + i);
}
```

```html
<ul id="list2">
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
  <li>Item 3</li>
  <li>Item 4</li>
</ul>
```

Using `filter()` allows you to do as the name suggests - filter down a set of matched objects as follows:

```js
$("li").filter(":first-child").addClass("test");
```

```css
.test {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>Number 1</li>
  <li>Number 1</li>
  <li>Number 1</li>
  <li>Number 1</li>
</ul>
```